# How do I display a popup error/success message when needed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a javascript code in the HTML file, there is also a mail.php file.

Main:

I'm trying to create an alert function using "SweetAlert".

I want the error message to show up when the form is not validated and the success message when it is (email sent).

Extra:

When the form is validated and the success message shows, the page reloads. Can the page reload only when I click on the "OK" button in the popup?

```
<form class="contact100-form validate-form alert" action="mail.php" method="POST">

            <span class="contact100-form-title">
                Contact
            </span>

            <div class="wrap-input100 rs1-wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Name is required">
                <span class="label-input100">Your Name</span>
                <input class="input100" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="wrap-input100 rs1-wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Valid email is required: ex@abc.xyz">
                <span class="label-input100">Email</span>
                <input class="input100" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email addess">
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Message is required">
                <span class="label-input100">Message</span>
                <textarea class="input100" name="message" placeholder="Your message here..."></textarea>
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="container-contact100-form-btn">
                <button class="contact100-form-btn">
                    <span>
                        Send
                        <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right m-l-7" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                </button>
            </div>
</form>



$('.alert').on('submit', function validateForm() {

    var name = document.forms["Form"]["name"].value;
    var email = document.forms["Form"]["email"].value;
    var message = document.forms["Form"]["message"].value;

    if (name == "" || email== "" || message == ""  ) {

        swal("Great!", "We'll get back to you soon!", "success");

        swal("Oops!", "Fill the blanks correctly!", "error" );
    }

  });
```

Right now, I'm getting an error message popup when the form is both not filled (not validated) and filled (validated form is submitted and I received the email).

Comment: A bit of HTML would help a lot. I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. Are you submitting the form via AJAX or not? And you mean you only want it to submit when you hit 'OK' on the alert? Is this a custom alert? What does `swal` do?

Comment: `if (confirm('Are you sure ?')) {
    // yes
} else {
    // Do nothing!
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have both the alerts in the same block.

Try this:

```
if (name == "" || email== "" || message == ""  ) {

    swal("Oops!", "Fill the blanks correctly!", "error" );
}
else
swal("Great!", "We'll get back to you soon!", "success");
```

As, I see your code, there's no mention of `"Form"` in there..

Edit your code with this..

```
<form class="contact100-form validate-form alert" name="Form" ..then the rest of code
```

Comment: Now nothing appears. Until I remove all 3 "var" variables.

(Still, only the error shows NO success when it is submitted)

Comment: @ahmdbadrn I don't understand why are you using `document.` when you are using jQuery `$('.alert')`, why not using jquery altogether to get the values.. ?

Comment: you can use something like `$("input[name=nameOfInputElement]").val()` to get  values of input elements, if you are not using `ids` for the same, ..plus, check your errors in console and try figuring out what's wrong with the code

Comment: And, if you are happy with `document.forms` then where is the `name` in your `form`, see my _edit_ in the answer

Comment: your right! The first issue was with them being in the same block and the second issue was I had no "name" in my "form". thank you for your help.

I am new to coding, can you please show me a full sample of how you would do it with $("input[name=nameOfInputElement]").val() ?

Comment: if it helped, then try marking it as answered.. that's done by clicking the tick-mark against my answer..it helps people .. Secondly, you can go through [jQuery tutorial](https://learn.jquery.com/) to learn more about that.. or simple make a [search](https://www.google.co.in/search?newwindow=1&safe=active&rlz=1C1CHBD_enIN750IN750&ei=N-M2XMTANoOVwASWrZTIDA&q=jquery+selecting+by+name&oq=jquery+selecting+by+name&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i22i30l9.97429.103555..103940...6.0..0.254.4020.0j7j12......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i20i263j0i10j0i22i10i30.Mc5bbJ7ABO0) for it :)

Answer (score 0):

SweetAlert uses promises to keep track of how the user interacts with the alert.

If the user clicks the confirm button, the promise resolves to true. If the alert is dismissed (by clicking outside of it), the promise resolves to null.

```
swal("Great!", "We'll get back to you soon!", "success")
.then((value) => {
      if(!value) {
          return false;
      }
});
```